# Getting a left margin and cannot figure out why

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, margin

I am creating a mobile drop-down menu and for some reason my nav-list is not taking up the entire `width:100%;` of the page. Well it is, but I am getting some kind of left margin next to the drop down menu. I have tried setting the `margin-left: 0;`, but that did not help. I don't even see where I have that margin set. I have also tried setting the `padding-left: 0;`. Nothing is working.

Please view in the viewport below 640px. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
 $('span.nav-btn').click(function () {
  $('ul.nav-list').slideToggle(500);
 })
 $(window).resize(function (){
  if ( $(window).width() > 600 ) {
   $('ul.nav-list').removeAttr('style');
  }
 });
```

```css
html ,body {
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
 font-family: "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
}

.header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: #191919;
}
.header_wrap {
 margin: auto 10%;
}
.logo {
 float: left;
 padding: 25px 0;
 font-size: 2.2em;
}
.logo a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFF;
}
.nav-list {
 text-decoration: none;
 float: right;
 list-style: none;
 z-index: 99999;
}
/*.nav-list li {
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 35px 20px;
 color: #FFF;
}*/
.nav-list > a {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 35px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-list > a > li {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color: #FFF;
}

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {

.logo {
 padding: 8px 0;
 font-size: 1.3em;
}
.header_wrap {
 margin: 0 5%;
}
.nav-list {
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
 display: none;
 top: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 999999999;
 position: absolute;
}
.nav-list > a {
 display: block;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.nav-btn {
 display: block;
 text-align: right;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding-top: 20px;
}
.nav-btn:before {
 background-image: url('http://greekgodmythology.com/icons/white-menu.png');
 background-size: 28px 28px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 28px;
 height: 28px;
 content:"";
 display: block;
 float: right;
}
```

```html
 <header class="header">
  <div class="header_wrap">
   <div class="logo"><a href="">ABC</a></div>
    <span class="nav-btn"></span>
    <ul class="nav-list">
     <a href="#"><li>A</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li>B</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li>C</li></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the rule that's adding the margin.

```
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {

    .header_wrap {
        margin: 0 5%;
    }

}
```

You are setting the top/bottom margin to `0` and the left/right margin to `5%`. This element contains your dropdown and therefore respects the margin on the parent element of `.header_wrap`.

Set it to `margin: 0;`. Though this will likely mess with the alignment of other elements in your menu. But that is where the margin is coming from.

One solution would be to not place your nav inside `.header_wrap`.

```html
<header class="header">

    <div class="header_wrap">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="">ABC</a>
        </div>
        <span class="nav-btn"></span>        
    </div>

    <ul class="nav-list">
        <a href="#"><li>A</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>B</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>C</li></a>
    </ul>

</header>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will think of something for it.